# Vb Listbox issue, queries appear blanc

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm experiencing some difficulties when trying to output a select query to my listbox.

The databaseconnection is working, In fact each time when I execute a query to the listbox1 it does indeed add a item.

But the item appears to be blank not containing any numeric nor string values.

Are there certain settings that need to be changed allowing a listbox to view query data? I did stumble upon certain random google hits in which people had similar issues and were told to change the column setting within the listbox it self. 
Unfortunately doing this had no effect for me.

Anyone with any logical ideas on what might be wrong? 
For the rest of my codes appears to be working just fine (database connection codes, query execution etc.)

Insightful help would be much appreciated!

---

Connection code:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String

Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet

Sub connect()

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\marten\Desktop\KassaSysteem\ShopDb.accdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource



End Sub
Sub con2()
    con.Open()

End Sub
Function sqlSelect(ByVal sqlString As String)

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, con)
    da.Fill(ds)
    Return ds

End Function

Sub reset()
    ds.Reset()
End Sub
```

Query code:

```
  Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    db.connect()

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Artikelen '"
    ds = db.sqlSelect(sql)




    ListBox1.Items.Add(ds)




    db.reset()

End Sub
```

I used SELECT * just as an example, but even when selecting a specific table object. The output returns to a selectable blank line in the list box.

Comment: Without any code we are in the dark

Comment: Show the code where you select data from db + writing it to listbox

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and here [mcve] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: okay odd, how do I enable it in 2015 for it's not under options/debugging/general

Comment: never mind found it!

Comment: @MattWilko even while running the code with strict on works fine.. not even any errors visible..

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a DataSet as a Listbox item. You need to add each of the items that you are interested in. Something like this might show some data:

```
    For Each table As DataTable In ds.Tables
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            ListBox1.Items.Add(row.Field(Of String)(0))
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Even that had no effect, unfortunately.. 


I'm just trying to bind a product price to a button that adds it to the listbox so I then can multiply/add or divide it. 


So I actually only need 1 datarecord preferably 2, name and price but 1 should do the trick as wel. 

Or are the better ways to execute this, like using a textbox or any other information object?

Comment: Without seeing a better sql query (you should not use `SELECT *`) I couldn't really give a better example. Does your query actually return any data? The debugger is your friend here

Comment: I used SELECT * as a example to axplain what I'm doing. I'm actually only interested in getting 2 records out of a table. 

And yes both the code and query work fine. 

When I'm using 

   ds = db.sqlSelect(sql)
    MsgBox( ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
    ListBox.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

It does answer with the correct information about the table. 
( amount of items in it) But even when using a single select like
SELECT product_nm FROM PRODUCTS WHERE product_nr = 1
The listbox shows nothing but a blank selectable line.